# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT en laravel 10

Tags: laravel, cookies

tengo un proyecto en laravel 10 que me corre bien en el servidor local, pero cuando lo pongo en el servidor remoto me da ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT luego de un tiempo de carga, o sea, la pagina carga parcialmente, las ultimas imagenes y archivos en cargar ya no cargan y me muestra ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Ademas, justo antes de comenzar a dar ese error, me sale la advertencia de "Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab." por lo que pensé que podría ser problemas con las cookies (estoy cargando unos video de youtube con un iframe)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues de buscar información por internet, decidí cambiar mi archivo de configuración

```
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),
'http_only' => false,
'same_site' => "none",
```

pero esto no solucionó en absoluto nada. He optimizado la carga de la página, los metodos y consultas a base de datos, pero demora en cargar 823ms, que no es un mal tiempo, entonces, ya no me queda nada por intentar, si alguien pudiera ayudarme le agradecería, saludos!!!

Comment: Pareciera ser que tenes mal las rutas de las imagenes. Validaste tener el symlink del storage en el server? php artisan storage:link

Comment: Gracias por responder, revisé las imagenes, estan bien las rutas y sí tengo el acceso directo a storage en public en el servidor, lo curioso es que cargan las primeras imagenes y recursos en general, pero despues de un tiempo, comienza aparecer este error, y se satura todo el servidor, si refresco nuevamente la pestaña me dice que el "sitio a tardado demasiado en responder", y tengo que cambiar de red para que vuelva a cargar, no se si será tema de configuración del servidor, pero llevo casi una semana buscando información y aun no he resuelto el problema.

Comment: Será alguna configuración del servidor? Buscaste algún log del apache o nginx?

Comment: Yo creo que debe ser alguna configuracion del servidor, pero no se cual, el servidor es nginx, porque cuando me da el error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT en mi web tampoco puedo acceder al servidor gitlab instalado en ese propio servidor (me pone que el sitio a demorado demasiado tiempo en responder), entonces tengo que desconectarme de la red y conectarme con otro ip para poder entrar a gitlab nuevamente (o esperar cerca de media hora para volver a acceder). He revisado los logs y no aparece ningun error, los logs no muestran nada en lo absoluto.

Comment: No sera alguna regla de firewall uwf o fail2ban?

Comment: No se que pueda haber sido, simplemente aumente los recursos del servidor, y ya todo comenzó a funcionar como el local, quizas el servidor se estaba quedando sin RAM, gracias por los consejos!

Comment: Y por lo que decis falta de recursos.

Comment: Puedes aumentar el tiempo de espera del servidor, ve al archivo `config/app.php` en la sección `url`  en el array `guzzle`. Aquí puedes encontrar la configuración para el tiempo de espera. Por defecto, el tiempo de espera está configurado en 300 segundos (5 minutos).